# Jackson: Parsing an object with an array of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working on a project where I'm integrating with a 3rd party service that returns a JSON response. I am using Jackson to deserialize the response into a Java POJO. The response is an object that has a few simple fields that Jackson is able to easily parse. However the response also contains an array with a single entry that is also an object. When Jackson attempts to deserialize it I get the top level object containing a list with the single entry in the list, however all of the fields for the single entry in the list are null. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE: after setting FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to true, I am getting the following stack trace. Still not sure why it is having issues with the wrapped "RecurringDetail" object in the array.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "RecurringDetail" (class com.adyen.www.models.RecurringDetail), not marked as ignorable (19 known properties: "variant", "contractTypes", "tokenDetails", "aliasType", "name", "creationDate", "firstPspReference", "elv", "card", "additionalData", "shopperName", "socialSecurityNumber", "billingAddress", "bank", "recurringDetailReference", "paymentMethodVariant", "alias", "acquirer", "acquirerAccount"])
 at [Source: response.json; line: 5, column: 33] (through reference chain: com.adyen.www.models.RecurringDetailsResult["details"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.adyen.www.models.RecurringDetail["RecurringDetail"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1094)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1470)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1448)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:499)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:101)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2759)
```

JSON

```
{
"creationDate": "2017-01-26T23:11:20+01:00",
"details": [
    {
        "RecurringDetail": {
            "acquirer": "TestPmmAcquirer",
            "acquirerAccount": "TestPmmAcquirerAccount",
            "additionalData": {
                "cardBin": "440000"
            },
            "alias": "B133243153928547",
            "aliasType": "Default",
            "card": {
                "expiryMonth": "8",
                "expiryYear": "2018",
                "holderName": "Steve HAll",
                "number": "0008"
            },
            "contractTypes": [
                "RECURRING"
            ],
            "creationDate": "2017-01-26T23:11:20+01:00",
            "firstPspReference": "8524854686798738",
            "paymentMethodVariant": "visadebit",
            "recurringDetailReference": "8414854686802111",
            "variant": "visa"
        }
    }
],
"invalidOneclickContracts": "false",
"lastKnownShopperEmail": "someones@email.com",
"shopperReference": "xggZcGauSSG5jP+akIlijQ=="
}
```

Unit Test

```
public class RecurringDetailResultTest {

public static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -174113593500315394L;
    {
        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS, true);
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }
};

@Test
public void testParseRecurringDetailResulte() throws IOException {

    RecurringDetailsResult result = mapper.readValue(new File("response.json"), new TypeReference<RecurringDetailsResult>(){});
    if (result.getDetails() != null && !result.getDetails().isEmpty()) {
        RecurringDetail detail = result.getDetails().get(0);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(detail.getRecurringDetailReference())) {
            fail("Recurring detail does not contain any information.");
        }
    } else {
        fail("No result details returned.");
    }

}

}
```

Model (Root object)

```
public class RecurringDetailsResult 
    implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5297684963950973136L;
private Date creationDate;
private String shopperReference;
private List<RecurringDetail> details;
private String lastKnownShopperEmail;

@JsonGetter("creationDate")
public Date getCreationDate ( ) { 
    return this.creationDate;
}

@JsonSetter("creationDate")
public void setCreationDate (Date value) { 
    this.creationDate = value;
}

@JsonGetter("shopperReference")
public String getShopperReference ( ) { 
    return this.shopperReference;
}

@JsonSetter("shopperReference")
public void setShopperReference (String value) { 
    this.shopperReference = value;
}

@JsonGetter("details")
public List<RecurringDetail> getDetails ( ) { 
    return this.details;
}

@JsonSetter("details")
public void setDetails (List<RecurringDetail> value) { 
    this.details = value;
}

@JsonGetter("lastKnownShopperEmail")
public String getLastKnownShopperEmail ( ) { 
    return this.lastKnownShopperEmail;
}

@JsonSetter("lastKnownShopperEmail")
public void setLastKnownShopperEmail (String value) { 
    this.lastKnownShopperEmail = value;
}

}
```

Model (the object in the array, all of the fields of this guy are null when Jackson deserializes the JSON)

```
public class RecurringDetail 
    implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5302883242997268343L;
private String name;
private Date creationDate;
private Card card;
private ELV elv;
private Address billingAddress;
private String additionalData;
private Name shopperName;
private String socialSecurityNumber;
private String recurringDetailReference;
private BankAccount bank;
private String alias;
private String aliasType;
private TokenDetails tokenDetails;
private String variant;
private String paymentMethodVariant;
private String firstPspReference;
private List<String> contractTypes;
private String acquirer;
private String acquirerAccount;

@JsonGetter("name")
public String getName ( ) { 
    return this.name;
}

@JsonSetter("name")
public void setName (String value) { 
    this.name = value;
}

@JsonGetter("creationDate")
public Date getCreationDate ( ) { 
    return this.creationDate;
}

@JsonSetter("creationDate")
public void setCreationDate (Date value) { 
    this.creationDate = value;
}

@JsonGetter("card")
public Card getCard ( ) { 
    return this.card;
}

@JsonSetter("card")
public void setCard (Card value) { 
    this.card = value;
}

@JsonGetter("elv")
public ELV getElv ( ) { 
    return this.elv;
}

@JsonSetter("elv")
public void setElv (ELV value) { 
    this.elv = value;
}

@JsonGetter("billingAddress")
public Address getBillingAddress ( ) { 
    return this.billingAddress;
}

@JsonSetter("billingAddress")
public void setBillingAddress (Address value) { 
    this.billingAddress = value;
}

@JsonGetter("additionalData")
public String getAdditionalData ( ) { 
    return this.additionalData;
}

@JsonSetter("additionalData")
public void setAdditionalData (String value) { 
    this.additionalData = value;
}

@JsonGetter("shopperName")
public Name getShopperName ( ) { 
    return this.shopperName;
}

@JsonSetter("shopperName")
public void setShopperName (Name value) { 
    this.shopperName = value;
}

@JsonGetter("socialSecurityNumber")
public String getSocialSecurityNumber ( ) { 
    return this.socialSecurityNumber;
}

@JsonSetter("socialSecurityNumber")
public void setSocialSecurityNumber (String value) { 
    this.socialSecurityNumber = value;
}

@JsonGetter("recurringDetailReference")
public String getRecurringDetailReference ( ) { 
    return this.recurringDetailReference;
}

@JsonSetter("recurringDetailReference")
public void setRecurringDetailReference (String value) { 
    this.recurringDetailReference = value;
}

@JsonGetter("bank")
public BankAccount getBank ( ) { 
    return this.bank;
}

@JsonSetter("bank")
public void setBank (BankAccount value) { 
    this.bank = value;
}

@JsonGetter("alias")
public String getAlias ( ) { 
    return this.alias;
}

@JsonSetter("alias")
public void setAlias (String value) { 
    this.alias = value;
}

@JsonGetter("aliasType")
public String getAliasType ( ) { 
    return this.aliasType;
}

@JsonSetter("aliasType")
public void setAliasType (String value) { 
    this.aliasType = value;
}

@JsonGetter("tokenDetails")
public TokenDetails getTokenDetails ( ) { 
    return this.tokenDetails;
}

@JsonSetter("tokenDetails")
public void setTokenDetails (TokenDetails value) { 
    this.tokenDetails = value;
}

@JsonGetter("variant")
public String getVariant ( ) { 
    return this.variant;
}

@JsonSetter("variant")
public void setVariant (String value) { 
    this.variant = value;
}

@JsonGetter("paymentMethodVariant")
public String getPaymentMethodVariant ( ) { 
    return this.paymentMethodVariant;
}

@JsonSetter("paymentMethodVariant")
public void setPaymentMethodVariant (String value) { 
    this.paymentMethodVariant = value;
}

@JsonGetter("firstPspReference")
public String getFirstPspReference ( ) { 
    return this.firstPspReference;
}

@JsonSetter("firstPspReference")
public void setFirstPspReference (String value) { 
    this.firstPspReference = value;
}

@JsonGetter("contractTypes")
public List<String> getContractTypes ( ) { 
    return this.contractTypes;
}

@JsonSetter("contractTypes")
public void setContractTypes (List<String> value) { 
    this.contractTypes = value;
}

@JsonGetter("acquirer")
public String getAcquirer ( ) { 
    return this.acquirer;
}

@JsonSetter("acquirer")
public void setAcquirer (String value) { 
    this.acquirer = value;
}

@JsonGetter("acquirerAccount")
public String getAcquirerAccount ( ) { 
    return this.acquirerAccount;
}

@JsonSetter("acquirerAccount")
public void setAcquirerAccount (String value) { 
    this.acquirerAccount = value;
}

}
```

Comment: I've tried with this UNWRAP_SINGLE_VALUE_ARRAYS set to both true and false. I've also tried this with ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY set to both true and false.

Comment: I've set DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to true and am now getting this stack trace

Comment: Are you free to change the json? the problem is your outer object doesn't have a root value but your inner object does.

Comment: No. I am not free to change the JSON. It is a response from a third party service. I've run it through a couple linters though and it is valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think to do is to make your java objects look like your Json. Because this Json has a wrapped inner object but not the outer object you would have to have a similar wrapping in java.  It isn't elegant but works.

```
public class RecurringDetailsResult implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Date creationDate;
    private String shopperReference;
    private List<RecurringDetailWrapper> details;
    private String lastKnownShopperEmail;

    // getters and setters here. No need for any @JsonGetter or @JsonSetter annotations
}


@JsonRootName("RecurringDetail")
public class RecurringDetailWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("RecurringDetail")
    RecurringDetail recurringDetail;

    public RecurringDetail getRecurringDetail() {
        return recurringDetail;
    }

    public void setRecurringDetail(RecurringDetail recurringDetail) {
        this.recurringDetail = recurringDetail;
    }
}


public class RecurringDetail implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5302883242997268343L;

    private String name;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Card card;
    private AdditionalData additionalData;
    private String socialSecurityNumber;
    private String recurringDetailReference;
    private String alias;
    private String aliasType;
    private String variant;
    private String paymentMethodVariant;
    private String firstPspReference;
    private List<String> contractTypes;
    private String acquirer;
    private String acquirerAccount;

    public class AdditionalData {
        String cardBin;

        public String getCardBin() {
            return cardBin;
        }

        public void setCardBin(String cardBin) {
            this.cardBin = cardBin;
        }
    }

    // getters and setters here. No need for any @JsonGetter or @JsonSetter annotations

}
```

Then in your unit test:

```
@Test
public void testParseRecurringDetailResulte() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ID41901838.json");

    ObjectReader objectReader = mapper.readerFor(RecurringDetailsResult.class);
    RecurringDetailsResult result = objectReader.readValue(inputStream);

    if (result.getDetails() != null && !result.getDetails().isEmpty()) {
        RecurringDetailWrapper detail = result.getDetails().get(0);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(detail.getRecurringDetail().getRecurringDetailReference())) {
            fail("Recurring detail does not contain any information.");
        }
    } else {
        fail("No result details returned.");
    }
}
```

I posted the full working code here:
https://github.com/teacurran/java-experiments/tree/master/stackoverflow-sandbox/src/main/java/com/wirelust/stackoverflowsandbox/ID41901838

Comment: Thank you. Adding the wrapper object to my java model worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your current structure will work for the response JSON as below (an extra named layer is removed)

```
{
"creationDate": "2017-01-26T23:11:20+01:00",
"details": [
     {
            "acquirer": "TestPmmAcquirer",
            "acquirerAccount": "TestPmmAcquirerAccount",
            "additionalData": {
                "cardBin": "440000"
            },
            "alias": "B133243153928547",
            "aliasType": "Default",
            "card": {
                "expiryMonth": "8",
                "expiryYear": "2018",
                "holderName": "Steve HAll",
                "number": "0008"
            },
            "contractTypes": [
                "RECURRING"
            ],
            "creationDate": "2017-01-26T23:11:20+01:00",
            "firstPspReference": "8524854686798738",
            "paymentMethodVariant": "visadebit",
            "recurringDetailReference": "8414854686802111",
            "variant": "visa"
        }
],
"invalidOneclickContracts": "false",
"lastKnownShopperEmail": "someones@email.com",
"shopperReference": "xggZcGauSSG5jP+akIlijQ=="
}
```

For named object maybe you can try something like

```
public class RecurringDetailsResult 
    implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5297684963950973136L;
private Date creationDate;
private String shopperReference;
private List<Map<String,RecurringDetail>> details;
private String lastKnownShopperEmail;

@JsonGetter("creationDate")
public Date getCreationDate ( ) { 
    return this.creationDate;
}

@JsonSetter("creationDate")
public void setCreationDate (Date value) { 
    this.creationDate = value;
}

@JsonGetter("shopperReference")
public String getShopperReference ( ) { 
    return this.shopperReference;
}

@JsonSetter("shopperReference")
public void setShopperReference (String value) { 
    this.shopperReference = value;
}

@JsonGetter("details")
public List<Map<String, RecurringDetail>> getDetails ( ) { 
    return this.details;
}

@JsonSetter("details")
public void setDetails (List<Map<String, RecurringDetail>> value) { 
    this.details = value;
}

@JsonGetter("lastKnownShopperEmail")
public String getLastKnownShopperEmail ( ) { 
    return this.lastKnownShopperEmail;
}

@JsonSetter("lastKnownShopperEmail")
public void setLastKnownShopperEmail (String value) { 
    this.lastKnownShopperEmail = value;
}

}
```